# Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed while using firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app for IoT devices. My app has different activities for fetching data from different sensors.
Every activity receives data on a button click. Whenever I press the button I get the following error.

```
 confirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Get your custom_toast.xml layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));

                //Initializing the text views
                EditText editText =  findViewById(R.id.link2);
                final String link2 = editText.getText().toString();

                EditText editText1 =  findViewById(R.id.idvalue);
                final String StringValue = editText1.getText().toString();


                //Adding functionality to the text views
                fire2 = new Firebase("https://iotsense.firebaseio.com/");
                Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2+"/S1");
                fireChild.setValue("4");

                // Read from the database
                myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                        // whenever data at this location is updated.

                        if(StringValue.length()>0 && link2.length()>0) {

                            try {
                            status = dataSnapshot.child(link2 + "/Analog").getValue().toString();}
                            catch (NullPointerException ignored){}

                            if(status==null){
                                TextView text4 = layout.findViewById(R.id.text4);
                                text4.setText(" Error: Wrong ID. ");
                                // Toast...
                                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 540);
                                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.setView(layout);
                                toast.show();
                                return;
                            }
                            else {
                                analogvalue = Integer.parseInt(status);

                                pin.setText(status);

                                final int value = Integer.parseInt(StringValue);
                                if (analogvalue > value) {
                                    Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin1");
                                    fireChild.setValue(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
                                    Firebase fireChild1 = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin2");
                                    fireChild1.setValue(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());

                                }
                                if (analogvalue <= value) {
                                    if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                                    if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LOW")) {Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin1"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
                                    if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("HIGH")){Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("LOW");}
                                    if(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LOW")) {Firebase fireChild = fire2.child(link2 + "/Pin2"); fireChild.setValue("HIGH");}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

```
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132932(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 21(744KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 35MB/40MB, paused 1.556ms total 109.059ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 94569(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 38MB/40MB, paused 8.078ms total 68.990ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 101736(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 39MB/40MB, paused 5.349ms total 81.087ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48181(1662KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 40MB/40MB, paused 5.361ms total 56.784ms
```

Comment: Those are not error messages.  They are informational messages about garbage collection, which happens naturally in all apps.  You can tell because each line begins with an uppercase "I", and each mentions "GC".

Comment: @DougStevenson how can I avoid this because of this my app stopes working.

Comment: Apps don't stop working because of garbage collection.  GC happens in all apps, and sometimes very frequently.  Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing much work in onClick, that will **do all the same thing when you click the button.**

It can cause unnecessary memory allocations, so they are doing a lot of GC as you see.

I suggests you to move some codes inside the onClick like

- Code to get the views like findViewById, view variables also
- Codes of firebase that you don't have to change dynamically
- Codes to instantiate and setting up the toast messages